# Use Linq to sum up data (double type) error. Object must be of the type Int32

Tags: linq

I want to sum up a group of double type values, but I got a run time Exception like: `Object` must be of the type `Int32` on the line  : resultSet.Sum(d => d.Data).

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    double sum = 0;
    DateTime timeSpot1 = fromDate.AddDays(i - 1);
    DateTime timeSpot2 = fromDate.AddDays(i);

    var resultSet = distributionDatePoint
                       .Where(d = > 
                                   d.Datetime.Day.CompareTo(timeSpot1) > 0 
                                && d.Datetime.Day.CompareTo(timeSpot2) < 0);
    if (resultSet != null) {
        sum = resultSet.Sum(d = > d.Data);
    }

    if (sum > 0) {
        chartData += sum.ToString("0.00");
    }
    else {
        chartData += "0,";
    }
}​
```

the `d.Data` is double type. And I tried to use `Sum()` in this way

```
resultSet.Sum<Double>(d => d.Data);
```

But the error remains.

Can anyone help me about this? Since I have been stuck for 30 mins......

Help~~~~

Comment: Exception? Compiler error? On the `resultSet.Sum` line?

Comment: @AdamRobinson, yes, I get an Exception on the resultSet.Sum line.

Comment: What does the debugger say is really in resultSet? I'd put a breakpoint on the 'if (resultSet != null)' line & inspect it in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here

```
var resultSet = distributionDatePoint 
                       .Where(d = >  
                                   d.Datetime.Day.CompareTo(timeSpot1) > 0  
                                && d.Datetime.Day.CompareTo(timeSpot2) < 0);
```

You are comparing an Int32 to a DateTime object.

You need to do something like

```
var resultSet = distributionDatePoint 
                       .Where(d = >  
                                   d.Datetime.Day.CompareTo(timeSpot1.Day) > 0  
                                && d.Datetime.Day.CompareTo(timeSpot2.Day) < 0);
```